# Convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{100\cdot \:101\cdot \:...\cdot \:\left(100+n\right)}{1\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot \left(2n-1\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether this is convergent or not:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{100\cdot \:101\cdot \:...\cdot \:\left(100+n\right)}{1\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot \left(2n-1\right)}$$

My problem is that I didn't really work with such series before, where I have $...$ inside the sum. I'm thinking I can just use the ratio test and it would tell me that my series is convergent. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Do you mean 
$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{100\cdot\color{red}{101}\cdots\left(100+n\right)}{1\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot \left(2n-1\right)}
$? Also, for $n = 1$, is the intended fraction $\frac{100\cdot 101}{1}$? Because that's what it looks like (in contrast to, let's say, $\frac{100}{1}$ or $\frac{100\cdot 101}{1\cdot 3}$).

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the error, didn't notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Do not worry too much about the complexity of the terms. You need to work $$S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$$

Consider $$a_n=\frac{100\times 101\times \cdots\times \left(100+n\right)}{1\times 3\times \cdots\times \left(2n-1\right)}$$ $$a_{n+1}=\frac{100\times 101\times \cdots\times \left(100+n\right)\times(101+n)}{1\times 3\times \cdots\times \left(2n-1\right)\times(2n+1)}$$ So, the ratio of two consecutive terms is just $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{n+101}{2 n+1}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Yes! This is how I solved it, but I didn't know if this was the correct approach. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome ! It is simple; just use the definition and the ususal tests.

Answer (score 3):

To prove it, don't be impressed with the $\dots$.

Take $N = 100$,

Split summation up to $N$ and above $N$:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{100} X_i + \sum\limits_{i=101}^{\infty} X_i$

The first part is convergent as is any finite summation.

The second part can be bounded by a constant (even if it is $200^{100}$) times a convergent sequence $1/2^n$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with 'split summation up to N and above N' :(